# Find the general solution in terms of Bessel functions: $t^2x'' + x' + x = 0, \quad t < 0, \text{ Hint: } s = 2\sqrt{t}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, bessel-functions

I was asked the following question:

Find the general solution in terms of Bessel functions:

$$t^2x'' + x' + x = 0, \quad t < 0, \text{ Hint: } s = 2\sqrt{t}$$

***My approuch***

I think that what I have to do is transform the given equation in one that has a form of a Bessel equation, and for that it must be used the *hint*.

- $\frac{ds}{dt} = t^{-1/2}$
- $\frac{dx}{dt} = \frac{dx}{ds}\frac{ds}{dt} = t^{-1/2} \frac{dx}{ds}$
- $\frac{d^2x}{dt^2} = \frac{d}{dt} \Big( \frac{dx}{dt} \Big) = \frac{d}{dt} \Big( t^{-1/2} \frac{dx}{ds} \Big) = \frac{d}{dt}t^{-1/2} \frac{dx}{ds} +  t^{-1/2}\frac{d}{dt} \Big( \frac{dx}{ds} \Big) = \frac{-1}{2} t^{-3/2} \frac{dx}{ds} + t^{-1/2} \frac{d}{ds} \Big( \frac{dx}{ds} \Big) \frac{ds}{dt} = \frac{-1}{2} t^{-3/2} \frac{dx}{ds} + t^{-1} \frac{d^2x}{ds^2}$

So, in the given equation, now we have:

$$
\begin{align}
t^2\Big( \frac{-1}{2} t^{-3/2} \frac{dx}{ds} + t^{-1} \frac{d^2x}{ds^2} \Big) + t^{-1/2}\frac{dx}{ds} + x  &= 0 \\
\frac{-1}{2}t^{1/2}\frac{dx}{ds} + t\frac{d^2x}{ds^2} + t^{-1/2}\frac{dx}{ds} + x &= 0 \\
\frac{-1}{2} \frac{s}{2} \frac{dx}{ds} + \frac{s^2}{4} \frac{d^2x}{ds^2} + \frac{2}{s} \frac{dx}{ds} + x &= 0 \\
s^2 \frac{d^2x}{ds^2} + \Big( \frac{8}{s} - s \Big)\frac{dx}{ds} + 4x &= 0
\end{align}
$$

Which doesn't have a Bessel-equation form. So please, can anybody enlighten me? Thanks in advanced!

Comment: Are you sure this is a Bessel equation?

Comment: Also if $t<0$ how can we do substitution $s=2\sqrt{t}$?

Comment: Well, I was kind of asking me the same thing. But I am not sure. So the given initial equation can not be transform into a bessel equation, right??

Comment: As far as your efforts show, it can't!

Comment: But my efforts just took the _hint_, how can I know that the given equation can not be transform into a bessel-equation form for any possible substitution??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We see that $t=0$ is not a regular singularity of the equation
$$x''+\dfrac{1}{t^2}x'+\dfrac{1}{t^2}x=0$$
then this is not a [Bessel differential equation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BesselDifferentialEquation.html).

Comment: but $x$ is a function of $t$, I mean: $x = x(t)$. but wait...$t = 0$ is a non-regular singular point!

Comment: yes, I meant  $t=0$.